# Too new android google play version

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have created an android application using Android Studio. I have this code in the manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

and the value for @integer/google_play_services_version is 520800 (value added automatically when I linked the Google play library. No hardcode there).

This is the link between the library and the project

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

also auto generated when I have added the Google play library from the menu.

The application works fine, bun when I generate a signed APK and try to upload it to the Google market it gives me an error saying that I am trying to upload an APK which uses google play version 5208000 and I should use version 5100000 or lower.

I have tryed to google_play_services_version into 5100000 but then the application stops working from the beginning.

How should I make my app runnable and valid for uploading on the market?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem is with this instruction:

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

the **play-services:+** means that it will pack the very latest play-services version. The problem is that the very latest play-services version available on the development environment is not yet fully published worldwide by Google, therefore not yet available to be used in official builds. So you have to use a version that it is indicating or lower..like this one: **play-services:5.0.89**.

So this one will work:

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

To find a list of available version, take a look at this folder in your SDK: extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/

Good luck!

Comment: This does the trick even tho android studio by default on the build gradle sets this to compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'.

Anyways thank you!

Comment: This is a side question. How do you know which other versions of play-services you have? (ex. You have alternative older version = 5.0.89)

Answer (score 8):

Use this setting in your app's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
}
```

I found the solution posten on the XDA Developers forum:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/coding/java-android/google-play-version-t2845409

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have same problems with your libraries. You should use the lib that supports last GP version. Please type logs for details.Also try to compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'`