# How can i change google play services version to 5100000 in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-play

I've developed an android application that works well, but when i try to publish in the Google Play Store, it gives me an error that says i have google play services version 6111000 and need to have google play services version 5100000 or lower.

I've found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258806/too-new-android-google-play-version) that already have a solution but its for Android Studio, and i am using Eclipse. So how can i do that in Eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: ok, i found the solution. i just download manually the old version of google services and imported it to the project. I think i need to wait some more time until the new version of google services finish the rollout. Then, maybe the play store accept the new version. If someone needs the old version 5089000, you can download here ->    http://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_5089000_r19.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play Services just finished the rollout of [Google Play Services 6.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/09/google-play-services-61.html) today. You should update the Google Play Services SDK to the new version and try publishing again.

Comment: I already have the most updated version of Google Play Services SDK. I've updated it today in Android SDK Manager.

Comment: And you've updated the project in Eclipse, making sure it is pointed at the new version?

Comment: I've referenced the new library in the project. Is that what you mean in pointing to new version?